# How can I display pre-roll VAST ads inside HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, ads, vast

So I have a website like YouTube and I want to monetize it. It uses simple HTML5 video player to display dynamic videos. I don't want to integrate any other player because my site is designed for HTML5 players. I have watched couple of videos about this, and neither of the source codes worked (It didn't display the ad itself). I use Adsterra VAST tag, so I don't know if it's their problem or not. I would be very happy if someone can help me with documentations or sample codes. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you would need to use IMA SDK for html5 player:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side

In there you can find the necessary code to do it,  sorry for the late reply i just found this ticket.